# MySQL compression on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, compression, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform

As the Google Cloud SQL is a managed instance of MySQL under the hood, limited to an absolute max on 2nd generation machines of 100GB of RAM, should I be compressing some of my table and index data ? I am designing a global system  so eventually the working set will probably exceed the 100GB.

Previously i've achieved performance improvements by compressing tables and indexes in SQL Server and Oracle systems that were memory bound.

I'm new to GCP, and consequently MySQL. Would the usage of compression still apply in this case? are there any such functions or procedures (like compression_estimate in SQL Server) I can run to assess if a table or index will benefit from the compression?

Comment: mysql reference manual states "Before creating a compressed table, make sure the innodb_file_per_table configuration option is enabled, and innodb_file_format is set to Barracuda. You can set these parameters in the MySQL configuration file my.cnf or my.ini, or with the SET statement without shutting down the MySQL server."   but there is no my.cnf on the cloud instance, so can this still be used?

Comment: Do you really need compressed?  A multi-terabyte datasets _may_ happily live on 100G machine.  What is your data like?  Text?  Blobs?  Lots of rows?  Care to share the `CREATE TABLEs`?

Comment: Keeping my data skinny, blobs, images, pdfs and large amounts of text are going to be stored in other parts of ther solution

Comment: @Rick James    Im just writing a one pager on how we could scale if required.. Do you know if compression is possible on CLoud SQL ?  ignoring whether our working dataset will require it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need compressed? A multi-terabyte datasets may happily live on 100G-RAM machine. What is your data like? Text? Blobs? Lots of rows? Care to share the `CREATE TABLEs`?

I don't have any details on Cloud SQL.  But...

Compression is usually not the first place to look when thinking of Scaling.  It has overhead (usually CPU, sometimes complexity).

- InnoDB's compression gives you about 2x.
- Outside compression (zip, etc) give about 3x for text. That is not very significant for "scaling".
- TokuDB and InfiniDB claim to get 10x, and I have heard supporting evidence for such.

"Scaling" usually involves Sharding or some other "distributed" technique.

RAM is not usually the limiting factor in Scaling; it is disk space. Or it could be any of several metrics - IOPs, network bandwidth, etc.

Scaling...

- Read scaling is 'easily' handled via Replication.
- Write scaling is not handled by any normal technique.
- Galera Cluster gives *some* write scaling.
- Sharding give a lot of write scaling, but at noticeable complexity in the application.
- MySQL's NDB Cluster gives some write scaling, but it is usually limited to niche applications, and not for general use.  (And the setup is quite complex.)
- I am skeptical of any off-the-shelf *database* "scaling" -- beware of marketing hype.  (Web servers are easy to scale; databases are not.)